# Facebook comments on a product appears in all other product page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-page, facebook

I have set up the [facebook Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#moderation-setup-instructions) in `product view page` and all product pages are displaying same comments. How to avoid displaying other product's comment?

Comment: Change url  in facebook comment for product pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using the same path for product add   `product url`

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" data-numposts="5"></div>
```